# How to change tile image in credential provider in windows 7 using C++?

Tags: c++, windows-7, credential-providers

I am doing final year project..I want change tile image in windows-7 using credential provider when the user password is fail instead of throw an error message..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show us, what you have done till now. You can change tile image in SetBitmapValue.